# selenium WebDriver not finding elements on a modal

Tags: selenium-rc

I am using selenium webdriver not straight selenium-rc

I have a modal login prompt that come up when you click the login button. Its just a simple div such as ->   that has a few frame containers in it.

I can get selenium to open the modal and selenium can find the modal cause I check to see if it is up so it does no the container is open

enderedWebElement resultsDiv = (RenderedWebElement)driver.findElement(By.className("logincontentcontainer"));

But it cannot find any controls on the modal such as text box or buttons. I have tried looking by name, id, classname....  no luck.  firebug see's the controls fine.  I have several sleeps to make sure its not a race condition.

I should add the modal that comes up is a container with 2 iframes the controls I need are in 1 iframe what contains a form with the controls on that form.  not sure if that matters

Answer (score 4):

Are you switching to the frame before you try to find any elements in it?  If you're not, that could be your problem.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frameName");
```

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/09_webdriver.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Comment: wow that did it.  I had tried to switch to the main modal that launches not the ind iframe.  2 hours of my life I will never get back

Comment: @AdamPrax the link is broken